# Spawning a process

Tags: python, multithreading, spawn

What exactly does the line

> spawn a process that would run it autonomously

means, please explain.

> Language Python
>
> Server Linux

An example will be better for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to create a subprocess that does something ("runs it") independently of your main python process.  You can read up on the Python `subprocess` module for details.  Without knowing your exact needs, it's hard to suggest what is specifically best for you, but here's an extremely simple example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("/bin/date")
```

This will run `/bin/date`, and the output will go to standard error.

Comment: There are no specific needs I was going through some project's detail, where this sentence popped. I'm familiar with spawning but the word autonomously bothered me. Any-ways I'll look forward for your suggestion.

Comment: Well, autonomously just means independently of your main process.  As in, spawn the process and then let it run on its own.